# Windows 7 Pro as host to 2008 R2 guest Virtual? HyperV?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I currently host a Windows 2003 Test Server using Windows 2005 Virtual Server under Windows 7 Pro.  I recall having to do some hacking to get Virtual Server 2005 to run under Windows 7 - can't recall what I had to do - but it does run and has been stable.  However there are some limitation in that I can't seem to connect USB drives and can't seem to mount Clonedrive ISOs.  Anyways, looking forward now to new and better things and a bit confused about what's possible.

Is there support for a 2008 R2 Sever VM guest under a HyperV on Windows 7 Pro Host? If not, what are my options?  I'm reading some things indicating this might be available soon.

If not, 'm trying to point Virtual Server 2005 R2 to an ISO or a clonedrive with no luck.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Microsoft will support it, if that's what your question is.

My recommendation, if you're going to go with unsupported virtualization technology, is to run Oracle VirtualBox on your host machine. It's much easier to install and manage than Virtual Server, and does support Windows 7. Though, again, I doubt Microsoft will support it, and the open source edition of VirtualBox is not supported by Oracle.